# Pushing content down with open Hamburger Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making website using Bootstrap framework . And I noticed on activation the "so called Hamburger icon " it would be great to slide down the content under it. I was lurking on stackoverflow for solution but i couldnt implement anything in my code

```
<head>
<title>| Web Programiranje |</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animations.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.paramore.net/sites/g/files/g2000001591/themes/mythemes/acq_paramore_v5/images/favicon_5.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
```

```
<body> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span style="color:white;">Grumpy Wizard</span></a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><b>HOME</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><b>ABOUT US</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="products.html"><b>PRODUCTS</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="team.html"><b>TEAM</b></a></li> 
                <li><a href="contact.html"><b>CONTACT</b></a></li> 
        </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="jumbotron_header">Grumpy Wizard!</h1> 
            <p>This page will grow as we add more and more components from Bootstrap...</p>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
          });
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Just to be sure; you want the menu to overlay the divs beneath it right? Because I just copy/pasted your code and it's pushing the content down just fine, like you're saying in the title. Could you try to be more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: it doesn't push content when i try